How do I use the transformprocessor to add a spanevent to a span?
I would like to use the transformprocessor via OTTL to add a span event to an existing span.  Unfortunately, as the transformprocessor is in the contrib collector, I do know that it's undergoing a lot of active development and the documentation doesn't describe how to work with events via append.
I have tried this and many variations like this in the configuration:
processors:
  transform/test:
    trace_statements:
      - context: span
        statements:
          - append(events, [{"name":"new-span"}]) where attributes["condition"] != nil

What is the proper way to use the transformprocessor to add a new entry to the events context?
